# Use a custom stylus package with webpack?

Tags: webpack, config, node-modules, stylus

I have a custom stylus package hosted in a private github repo which I include in my package manifest. After an `npm install` it is now in my `node_modules` directory with a directory structure something like:

```
node_modules
|
----my-custom-package
    |
     ----package.json
         webpack.config.js
         src/
         |
         ----index.js (which just imports css/index.styl)
             css/
             |
             ----index.styl
                 ...bunch of other .styl files
```

Using webpack 1.13 and stylus loader 2.5.1, how do I set it up to be able to import and use everything from my custom package? Is there something in my webpack config file that can load the files? Do I include some kind of `@require 'my-custom-package'` in my base .styl file? An `import 'my-custom-package'` in my entry `App.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

In my app's `index.styl` I required the custom styl file (`~` being shorthand for `node_modules` directory):

```
@require '~my-custom-package/src/css/index';
```

Then in my webpack config I edited my stylus loader to include the path to my custom package AND added `resolve url` so that stylus-loader could resolve relative paths in my custom package styl files:

```
{
    test: /\.styl$/i,
    include: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'my-custom-package')
    ],
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader?resolve url'
  }
```